# WCF Workflow service application and state machine in WF 4.0

Tags: wcf, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, state-machine

I am working a project where i need to create a state machine work flow in 4.0. I have installed .net framework 4 platform updates and i am able to get state machine and states in toolbox to work with. 
I have created a WCF workflow service application. I have currently 3 states in this.

State1 which executes a extenal process.
State2 which updates a database.
State3 populates some entity class.

Each state will be having a receiveandsend activity. I need to trigger each states individually from client. Cancreateinstance of each receive activity is made true.

I have to call this from a silverlight application. So i have added the service referance to this workflow in silverlight application.

when i execute the first state, its works fine and external process is executed.

But when i try to execute the next state by calling the next receive activity from client, its showing error as below.
"Operation 'ExecuteExternal|{http://tempuri.org/}IService' on service instance with identifier '4732d197-32c0-4591-87bc-fa0adb7ec43a' cannot be performed at this time. Please ensure that the operations are performed in the correct order and that the binding in use provides ordered delivery guarantees."

I think the WF is not waiting after first state is finished. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with Correlation handle helped me to solve this issue. 
Please find the answer in the below post
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/6a7d9069-d5a7-4410-b5dd-16325d0d8dc9

Answer (score 0):

Your state machine is not waiting for the message that you are sending.  The best way to troubleshoot this is with tracking.  I've added a behavior that will help you to Microsoft.Activities.  See my blog post [Using Workflow Services and Silverlight Together](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/05/18/using-workflow-services-and-silverlight-together.aspx)

Comment: Thanks man. I installed NuGet.
But when i try Install-Package Microsoft.Activities command, it is showing following error.

Install-Package : The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.Activities
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Wow - that is strange - never seen that before. What OS are you running?